# How to use old mysql data folder for new version of mysql?

Tags: mysql

Today I uninstalled the Mysql server(5.0) from my computer and saved a copy of the `data` folder. After then I installed a version of Mysql 5.7.38 and it worked fine then I transferred the `date` folder's data to the new version of mysql's data folder. It even showed the databases on using the command but when I tried to view the tables in the database it gave and error that `p.gabs does not exist` (p was the database name and gabs was table name in it).
So I again uninstalled the version and I am reinstalling it.

So I am asking if there is a way to do this easily that I may use old databases in newer version.

P.S. I am using Mysql only at a beginner level. So no big server or stuff ..

Comment: [Here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/137424/how-do-i-move-the-mysql-data-directory) you have a detailed explanation.

Comment: The data dictionaries in these versions have different formats. The data directory cannot be attached directly. Recommendation. Uninstall new version. Install old version. Restore data directory. Backup your data. Uninstall old version. Install new version. Restore your data from backup.

Comment: But when I install the old version the mysql service doesn't start.